# How to close "Properties" windows?

Tags: window

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a laptop.

When I open a “Properties” window for a drive, the left-hand fifth of the “Properties” window is off-screen, and I cannot close the window.

How do I get the whole window to appear, and how do I close it?

Comment: Hold `Alt` key and you will be able to move the window with a mouse from any place. Probably you have a wrong screen resolution.

Comment: You really dont want rep do you? :D

Comment: Pilot6 - Thank you. Using Alt+mouse works perfectly to move the window, revealing the "Close" button. When I click "System Settings/Displays", I get the error message "Could not get screen information", so I don't know what the screen resolution is.  I shall pursue this.